# Facebook API help

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Where do I go from here? This is almost just copy paste from the example provided in the sdk. I don't understand how people can build anything with this API?? How do I open the prompt screen for login etc? Where the heck does Facebook say something about that?

```
<?php

require 'fb_sdk/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APIID',
  'secret' => 'SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Permissions requested from the user.
$par = array();
$par['scope'] = 'user_about_me, read_friendlists';

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($par);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information on using the Graph for user authentication [here on Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

With `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($par);` the variable `$loginUrl` will contain a url to the authentication dialog. Most developers either present this to the user as a link or perform a redirect with javascript - eg:

```
   die('<script>top.location.href = "' . $loginUrl . '"</script>');
```

The other alternative is to use the JavaScript SDK with XFBML to authenticate (if you have cookies enable with both SDKs they will share session data) - example from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/):

```
<?php

require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user_profile) { ?>
      Your user profile is 
      <pre>            
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre> 
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>               
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>', 
          cookie: true, 
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also login purely with JavaScript using [FB.Login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       FB.logout(function(response) {
         console.log('Logged out.');
       });
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'user_about_me, read_friendlists'});
```

Comment: Good answer, as for @Jollygood: don't think of the API for the sake of it. It's there to *help* you with your app. Once you have a clear idea of what your app will offer, the integration points with Facebook APIs will be clear. Take this [sample](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) app as an example, you realize your app idea and conclude that you need the user full name,email,photo and friends from Facebook and use the API accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the comment :

```
// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($par);
}
```

SDK will take care of that, you need not worry about it.
The user details are there in $user_profile
do a  `echo"<pre>"; print_r($user_profile); echo"</pre>";` and you will get it.